# MIDI parser in Clojure

Tags: clojure, midi

I've start to write a midi parser https://gist.github.com/rubzyk/8453093

inspired by this article http://vishnumenon.com/2013/06/25/musical-chains-music-generation-with-clojure/

I'm stuck with tempo stuffs, i can't find a way to convert tempo change messages into bpm
i've tried to use the way explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/music21list/f9AboXHW0QE) but it gives me wrong tempi... like 3000+ bpm

any help is welcome

feel free to advice me for some modification/refactoring of the code

Comment: How are you currently trying to compute the BPM?

Comment: yes i do, currently i use this expression:                           (->> (apply format "0x%x%x%x" (.getData msg)) read-string (/ 60000000)) where msg is a the tempo change MetaMessage

Comment: Dividing 60,000,000 by the tempo value is correct. I don't know Clojure ...

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but why not use java interop for this? Java already has a very solid midi library in `javax.sound.midi`. I've rolled my own midi library before (not in clojure) and it's tricky to get right with all the bit fiddling.

Another option is [midi-clj](https://github.com/rosejn/midi-clj).